# Html table values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a html table like this:

```
     Invoice#          Due Date      Balance      Select 
      12345           12/25/2011    $1,356.00       X
      56789           12/30/2011    $1,000.00       X

      Total:                        $2,356.00
```

Below the table I have a textbox. When the checkbox in a row is selected or deselected, I want the value of the textbox to update to add or subtract the balance in the selected row, i.e. subtract the balance stated in the row when the checkbox is unchecked, and add it when checked. By default the boxes will be checked.

Comment: Is it acceptable to use jQuery to accomplish this?

Comment: Let me get this straight. You mean to say on clicking X, the input box's value will be updated with the corresponding row's balance cell?

Comment: @ HackedByChinese-yes.... jQuery is acceptable..... The table size will always vary. that means i have more no of rows

Comment: @SBR- yes clicking X, the input box's value will be updated with the corresponding row's balance cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming jQuery:

```
$('table input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var curBalance=new Number($("#textbox").val());
    var rowBalance=new Number($(this).parent().prev().text());

    var newNum=0;
    if (this.checked) newBalance=curBalance+rowBalance;
    else newBalance=curBalance-rowBalance;

    $("#textbox").val(newBalance);
});
```

Comment: If the check box is checked then i want to add otherwise i want to subtract and by default all check boxes are checked

Comment: edited to add or subtract as appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each  has no other child element like `<p>`,`<a>` & `<button>`, just contains text. If not, repeat the first statement till you reach the `<tr>` element.

```
function getBalance(e){
  e = e.parentElement; //get the parent of the <td>.
  e = e.children[2]; //get the 3rd <td> of that <tr>.
  //finally copy the textContent to the value attribute.
  document.getElementById(inputboxId).setAttribute('value', e.textContent);
  //e.innerText for older browsers.
}
```

Place an onclick event handler on the 4th column cells.

```
<td onclick='getBalance(this)'>X</td>
```

Comment: this does not add or subtract the value depending on whether the checkbox (and it is a checkbox, not an "X") is checked or unchecked